# Determine the number of pages in a PDF file

Tags: java, pdf

How can I determine the number of pages in a given PDF file, using a free/open source Java API?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) to load a PDF document and then call the [`getNumberOfPages`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getNumberOfPages()) method to return the page count.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("file.pdf"));
int count = doc.getNumberOfPages();
```

Comment: I used this in a utility method to check which documents had less than some number of pages to delete this. But then I had to close the doc with doc.close(), otherwise I couldn't delete it, because then it is closed only after some time when the doc object is deleted by the GC.

Comment: Note: you'll run out of memory if your PDF is larger than the available memory.

Comment: On pdfbox 3.0.0 u may choose to use "var doc = Loader.loadPDF(new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(pdfFile.toAbsolutePath().toString()))"

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to do this with [iText](http://itextpdf.com). See [this thread](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/find-the-number-of-pages-of-a-pdf-file-td2165768.html) for how to solve the problem. [Here](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=2) is chapter 2, which is incorrectly linked in the thread:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("SimpleRegistrationForm.pdf");
int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Comment: Note: you'll run out of memory if your PDF is larger than the available memory. You can pass a `ReaderProperties` with `setPartialRead(true)` to the constructor so the whole file won't be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get more information about PDF, please use below code. If document does not contain any of the information, it returns null.
This is pdfbox library of apache.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;

public class DocumentService {

    public void showDocumentInfo(){
        PDDocument document= PDDocument.load(new File("file.pdf"));
        PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();
        System.out.println( "Page Count=" + document.getNumberOfPages() );
        System.out.println( "Title=" + info.getTitle() );
        System.out.println( "Author=" + info.getAuthor() );
        System.out.println( "Subject=" + info.getSubject() );
        System.out.println( "Keywords=" + info.getKeywords() );
        System.out.println( "Creator=" + info.getCreator() );
        System.out.println( "Producer=" + info.getProducer() );
        System.out.println( "Creation Date=" + info.getCreationDate() );
        System.out.println( "Modification Date=" + info.getModificationDate());
        System.out.println( "Trapped=" + info.getTrapped() ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the class of `document` (and the library that class is from).

Comment: @mkl thanks you for valuable suggestion. I have added required information.

Comment: Ah, PDFBox. So you essentially propose the same approach as the accepted answer does.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it provides clearly the expected answer for OP's question and gives details about IMPORTS and much more information helpful to many other users. Thanks for this @ShaileshVikramSingh :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalPages = 0;
using (var pdfStream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
     totalPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generates the PDF with FOP, then you can use 
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

You can count the pages with the help of fop tags.

If it is just a simple pdf file from an external source, then you should check iText API.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution over google . Please find the solution bellow.

1.Either download the artifact "spire.pdf" or use the bellow dependency and repo into your pom.xml ,

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.e-iceblue</id>
        <name>e-iceblue</name>
        <url>https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>e-iceblue</groupId>
        <artifactId>spire.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

use this link to find latest maven dependency.
[enter link description here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/e-iceblue/spire.pdf?repo=e-iceblue-maven-public)

2. Use java code as bellow ,

   ```
   PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(Balance_Sheet_Blank-1.pdf");
    int numberOfPages=pdf.getPages().getCount();
   ```

Here numberOfPages is the total no of pdf page count .