# How to get the number of pages of a pdf file in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, fileinfo

Can you help me find out the number of pages of a pdf document on Android, that will support down to at least api version 16. I am extracting document information but can't see a solution to get the total amount of pages. This Is what I doo so far:

```
private void extractDocumentDataFromUri(Uri uri)
    {
        String[] dataFileds = new String[]{
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                OpenableColumns.SIZE};

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, dataFileds, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        contentUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
        title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));

        cursor.close();

        contentType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    }
```

Comment: This might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026971/page-count-of-pdf-with-java

Comment: @BidhanA It doesn't seam like there is a PDFReader object.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
private void countPages(File pdfFile) throws IOException {
    try {
       
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
            totalpages = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
            pdfRenderer.close()
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about devices with SDKs less than Lollipop??

Answer (score 3):

This solution works if you add the iTextG library to your libs folder. The library contains a class called **PdfReader**.

Try something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Your file path");
int aa = reader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: @"Krupa Patel" Will it support down to android api version 16? Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: I can't find the PdfReader object in either Android Studio or in the online documentation :(

Comment: `PdfReader` is an [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) class. You need the iTextG library if you want this to work.

Comment: You should have indicated that using this class requires the importation of a library..