# Find PDF page count without reading the whole file

Tags: java, pdf

My problem is the following:

There are some huge PDF files (>500MB) and I want to find their page count, using JAVA. If I use itext or pdfbox, I have to wait until it reads the whole file and most of the times this fails, because of the large size of the file or it just takes a lot of time.

So, I would like to know if there is any quick and efficient way to find the page count of a PDF file.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026971/page-count-of-pdf-with-java?rq=1

Comment: nope, I tried it and it still takes A LOT of time... I'm searching something like read the metadata and take the page count

Comment: No, metadata (if available) isn't for that.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate? [Page count of Pdf with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026971/page-count-of-pdf-with-java)

and from that's post, [Mark Storer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477771/mark-storer)'s answer:

> The itext API underwent a little overhaul. Now (in version 5.4.x) the
>   correct way to use it is to pass through java.io.RandomAccessFile:

```
int efficientPDFPageCount(File file) {
     RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
     RandomAccessFileOrArray pdfFile = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(
          new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(raf));
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile, new byte[0]);
     int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
     reader.close();
     return pages;
}
```

Comment: @user3519936 Please share the file in question and indicate an acceptable amount of time.