# no.of pages in pdf file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am reading a pdf file using "pdfbox";I am not getting the total number of pages in the pdf document..I don't know why this is happening.

```
try {
    parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
    parser.parse();
    cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size(); i++) {
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(i);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(i);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        if(i==11)
        System.out.println(parsedText/*.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9. ]+", "")*/);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        if (cosDoc != null)
            cosDoc.close();
        if (pdDoc != null)
            pdDoc.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size(); is not giving the no.of pages..can someone help me pls...

Comment: What is it giving? Is it null, zero, a significantly wrong number, or is it just out by 1?

Comment: Could it be that the file is encrypted? What version are you using? Btw the correct way to open a file is PDDocument.load() or PDDocument.loadNonSeq().

Comment: Or could it be that you have a XFA form?

Comment: pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size(); is giving zero

Comment: could not load the file using PDDocument.load()..that's why I am using the above way to load file

Comment: "could not load the file using PDDocument.load()" - what happened? What version are you using? Can you share the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is this method

```
pdDoc.getNumberofPages();
```

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getNumberOfPages()

Comment: pdDoc.getNumberofPages(); is also giving zero

Comment: yes..I am able to fetch all the contents from the file but not the no.of pages and page number of each page in the document.

Comment: I was able to resolve the same issue by using iText API instead of pdfbox. Not sure, but for me also, pdDoc.getNumberofPages() was not working for all pdfs. For some pdfs, it was giving zero number of pages. Able to resolve using: 
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
  int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();     Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134949/determine-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
...
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
...
...pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size()...
```

call

```
parser.getPDDocument();
pdDoc.getNumberofPages();
```